# Center Image in both directions

Tags: html, css

I guess, this question was asked already, but I didn't find a good solution for my problem.

I have the following constellation: I have a parent element and an image which can be in landscape or in portrait. My goal is - no matter what: I bring the image to a minimum width/height of 50px, so a part of the picture is going to overlap the parent. Now I would like to center the picture no matter what dimension it has.

Right now it looks similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/EYL25/ (In my case I would have set an additional class which determines the orientation, set by JavaScript - I don't like this solution, but couldn't find a better one)

```
<div class="wrap is-landscape">
    <div class="element">Element 1</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap is-portrait">
    <div class="element">Element 2</div>
</div>
```

But it should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4t76d/

Does anyone know a solution how I could center the inner element no matter what orientation and size it has?

Small addition: I'm looking for a solution without any JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You poorly have to use JavaScript.

```
.element
{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -{element-width / 2};
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -{element-height / 2};
}
```

You need to get the elements dimension and then set margin-left and -top.

Comment: Yes, I have that solution right now... but I'm looking for a solution without JavaScript.

Comment: As far as I know there is no simple solution without javascript.

Answer (score -3):

User CSS instead.

```
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: 1. position fixed makes the element "sticky" which is kind of not good in my situation, because I don't have only 2 elements but up to 1000 (depends on my users) 2. having set only top and left to 50% makes them not centered. See http://jsfiddle.net/LRS78/